# How to manipulate R files in Android project

Tags: android

I made an android app and it is currently being released on the play store. And I was in the process of adding an Activity to implement additional features.

During this process I encountered an unknown error.
`Splash` > `MainActivity` > `SecondActivity`
There are 3 activities like this.
And if `android:id="@+id/my_view_id"` is added after adding a certain view in the `xml` file of `SecondActivity`, an error occurs in `Splash` and the app is terminated.

I added a view in SecondActivity, but I don't know why Splash gives an error.

If Splash has a TextView inside a ConstraintLayout, the error message is like this.

```
TextView cannot cast to ConstraintLayout
```

If you don't add a new view to SecondActivity (with id), no error occurs.
Perhaps a problem occurred in the file that controls the id values of all views in the project. How can I solve it?

Why are these errors occurring?

(There is no duplicate id value in all activities.)

Comment: Can you show some code used in the `SecondActivity` which is causing this crash?

Comment: It works fine without any issues. Just adding `android:id="@+id/"` in SecondActivity gives an error in Splash.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution.

just i `make build > clean project`
and `build > rebuild project`

And I am able to run the app successfully.
I don't know what effect clean project and rebuild project has, but the app works without errors anyway.